# Folder Deletion of Eclipse Java EE File

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm going to college for programming at a tech school right now. I deleted a project in windows explorer on windows 7 ultimate 64.  I can't seem to delete the project inside Eclipse to reuse the folder in the same work space to do my programming homework projects.  Yes I need to use the same folders and work spaces for class.  I've already tried deleting the Eclipse folder, the meta data folder, and all of the Eclipse folders.  Doing all of this has netted me the result of Eclipse telling me I can't use the same folder because a project is already in it even though the folder has been deleted and remade.  I can't seam to find any possible reason how eclipse is remembering that there was a project there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this task.

Comment: Can you still see the folder in eclipse?

Comment: You claim to "need" to reuse the same folders and workspaces for your class...but you don't explain "why"; creating a new workspace is straightforward, and you won't have this headache of Eclipse thinking that the old workspace exists.

Comment: Same folder hierarchy for turning in projects into the professor.  If Eclipse can't handle such a fundamental process form a new IDE user who made a mistake, maybe it's not a worthy development tool.  I've deleted every file for Eclipse that I can find. How is it remembering this after deletion?

Comment: "_maybe it's not a worthy development tool_" Trust us, Eclipse is most definitely a worthy development tool. Don't think that just because you have encountered a problem that the entire IDE is not worth it.

Comment: I've tried deleting: C:\Eclipse I've also deleted: C:\Java\Homework\.metadata I've deleted: C:\Users\JoeDoe\AppData\Local\Eclipse I have also deleted all data in user profile temp and windows temp but eclipse keeps the project folder.  The only possibly thing I can think of if it's propagation the data it's acquired to my windows user profiles downloaded unziped dir.

Comment: It's very nice, I'm just frustrated I can't fix this.

Comment: Also there is no data into the C:\Java\Homework\CH8 folder either.  I searched the registry for Eclipse and haven't found anything either.

Comment: When I go to create a project in the deleted - same workspace folder IE new project for workspace C:\Java\Homework new project in C:\Java\Homework\CH8 it gives an error for:  C:\Java\Homework\CH8 overlaps the location of another project: 'CH8'.

Comment: When you say it "keeps the project folder", how are you telling this? When you delete the project folder, are you deleting it from inside Eclipse? Are you checking the box that removes the files from disk as well and not just from what is considered in the workspace (it's destructive and not undoable, so not the default).

Comment: Wow I feel dumber already.  If you go to create a new project in Eclipse it doesn't like having the project folder already crated even if it's empty.  IE CH8 isn't a valid project name because there was a folder already made.